# Is the ring of formal power series in $n$ variables the colimit of the powers of its maximal ideal

Tags: homological-algebra, noetherian, limits-colimits, formal-power-series

Let $\mathbb C[[t_1, ..., t_n]]$ be the noetherian local ring of formal power series in $n$ variables with a unique maximal ideal $\mathfrak{m}=(t_, ..., t_n)$. Then, there is a descending chain of ideals of $\mathbb C[[t_1, ..., t_n]]$ given by $(1)\supset\mathfrak{m}\supset\mathfrak{m}^2\supset\cdots\mathfrak{m}^p\supset\cdots$. It is a well-known fact that every module is the direct limit (colimit) of its finitely generated submodules. Is it true that $\mathbb C[[t_1, ..., t_n]]\cong colim_p\mathfrak{m}^p$ as $\mathbb C[[t_1, ..., t_n]]$-modules?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but for trivial reasons; I don't think this is the question you meant to ask. The colimit over any diagram $F : J \to C$ of shape $J$ such that $J$ has a terminal object $1$ is just the evaluation $F(1)$, which here is the unit ideal. So the same would be true of any descending chain of ideals starting at the unit ideal, in any ring.

There is a nontrivial statement which looks a bit like this, which is that $\mathbb{C}[[t_1, \dots t_n]]$ is the *limit* of the *quotients* $\mathbb{C}[[t_1, \dots t_n]/m^p$.

Comment: Which category do you take as $C$? Is it the category of $\mathbb C[[t_1, ..., t_n]]$-modules? So $colim_p F(p)=colim_{p\geq0}\mathfrak{m}^p=F(1)=(1)=\mathbb C[[t_1, ..., t_n]]$? Do I read your statement correctly?

Comment: Yes, that’s what I mean.

Comment: Ok, thanks. And the category $C$ is the category of $\mathbb C[[t_1, ..., t_n]]$-modules?

Comment: Yes, but it doesn't really matter where we take the colimit. Are you sure this is the question you meant to ask? It's true but tells you basically nothing.

Comment: As a matter of fact, I did mean to ask this question. I found it not very obvious although you say that it is useless. From your answer, I also infer that the same is true also for modules, such as, for example, $M[[t_1, ..., t_n]]$, where $M$ is a complex module: $M\supset M\mathfrak{m}\supset M\mathfrak{m}^2\supset\dots\supset M\mathfrak{m}^p\supset\dots$. We have again $M[[t_1, ..., t_n]]=colim_pM\mathfrak{m}^p$, don't, we? In fact, $\mathbb C[[t_1, ..., t_n]]=colim_p\mathfrak{m}^p$ is a special case of the isomorphism in the category of $\mathbb C[[t_1, ..., t_n]]$-modules, correct?

Comment: Yes, that's right. But again this is useless; almost none of the terms except the first term matter so I can't imagine what use you could possibly want to put this result to.

Comment: You are right. I made a typo. Can we represent the ring $\mathbb C[[t_1, ..., t_n]]$ not so trivially as the inverse limit $lim_{p\geq0}\mathfrak{m}^{p}/\mathfrak{m}^{p+1}$. I am aware of the standard representation of $\mathbb C[[t_1, ..., t_n]]$ as the inverse limit of $\{\mathbb C[t_1, ..., t_n]/\mathfrak{m}^p\}$.

Comment: If we take the natural inclusions $\mathfrak{m}^q\to\mathfrak{m}^p$ for $q\geq p$, these induce maps $f_{qp}: \mathfrak{m}^q/\mathfrak{m}^{q+1}\to\mathfrak{m}^p/\mathfrak{m}^{p+1}$. I take these to form an inverse system $\{\mathfrak{m}^p/\mathfrak{m}^{p+1}, f_{qp}\}$.

Comment: All of these maps are equal to zero; I am again pretty sure this isn't actually the question you want to ask. Can you just say what you're actually trying to do?

Comment: We can express $\mathbb C[[t_1, ..., t_n]]=\prod_{i_1+...+i_n\geq0}\mathbb Ct_1^{i_1}\cdots t_n^{i_n}$, so I wanted to check if this is can be reformulated as an inverse limit/ colimit of quotients $\mathfrak{m}^p/\mathfrak{m}^{p+1}$. You answer in the negative for limits. I want to express the formula above as either a limit or a colimit of something. That is what I am trying to do.

Comment: Then just say that! $\mathbb{C}[[t_1, \dots t_n]]$ can be thought of as the product $\prod_{p \ge 0} m^p/m^{p+1}$ in a suitable sense; this is a version of the associated graded construction (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associated_graded_ring).

Comment: What do you mean "thought of" "in a suitable sense"? Is there an isomorphism of $\mathbb C[[t_1, ..., t_n]]$-modules $\mathbb C[[t_1, ..., t_n]]=\prod_{p\geq0}\mathfrak{m}^p/\mathfrak{m}^{p+1}$ or there isn't? Isn't the product an inverse limit in general?Can't we write then $\mathbb C[[t_1, ..., t_n]]=lim_{p\geq0}\mathfrak{m}^p/\mathfrak{m}^{p+1}$?

Comment: No, it's not an isomorphism of $\mathbb{C}[[t_1, \dots t_n]]$-modules. A priori it's only an isomorphism of vector spaces but the product can be equipped with a multiplication (defined on Wikipedia) making it an isomorphism of algebras. It's a limit (not an inverse limit) but not inside either the category of $\mathbb{C}[[t_1, \dots t_n]]$-modules or algebras, and that notation would be very misleading because it suggests that there are maps involved in the limit diagram which there aren't, and it also makes the desired category in which to compute the limit ambiguous.

Comment: That is very interesting, indeed. Thanks. And we can also write $M[[t_1..., t_n]] =\prod_{p\geq0}M\mathfrak{m}^p/\mathfrak{m}^{p+1}$ for a complex vector space $M$ (not necessarily finite dimensional)?

Comment: Yes, that's right. Are you planning on actually using these results anywhere?

Comment: Not in a direct way. But understanding the different ways one can express and think of adic completions is a useful tool for work. I have always tried to avoid limits and colimits as much as possible.

Comment: Why? They're completely natural here.

Comment: Yes, indeed. I agree.

Comment: If I may continue the discussion, if we change the $\mathbb C$-module $M$ by an $\mathbb C[[t_1, ..., t_n]]$-module $N$, does the identity $N[[t_1, ..., t_n]]=\prod_{p\geq0}N\mathfrak{m}^p/\mathfrak{m}^{p+1}$ survives in the same form or do the quotients $\mathfrak{m}^p/\mathfrak{m}^{p+1}$ get absorbed in $N$ so that we are left with $N[[t_1, ..., t_n]]=\prod_{p\geq0} N$. I would intuitively think that $N[[t_1, ..., t_n]]$ should be isomorphic to $N$ as $\mathbb C[[t_1, ..., t_n]]$-modules.

Comment: What do you mean by $N[[t_1, \dots t_n]]$? Like I said, this isn't an isomorphism of $\mathbb{C}[[t_1, \dots t_n]]$-modules, so there's no reason to expect it to behave like one.

Comment: I mean $N[[t_1, \dots, t_n]]\cong N\hat\otimes_{\mathbb C}\mathbb C[[t_1, \dots, t_n]]$. Here, $N$ is not simply a complex vector space but a $\mathbb C[[t_1, ..., t_n]]$-module. For a complex vector space, the isomorphism of complex vector spaces $N[[t_1, \dots, t_n]]\cong\prod_{p\geq0}\mathfrak{m}^p/\mathfrak{m}^{p+1}$ can always be turned into an isomorphism of $\mathbb C[[t_1, ..., t_n]]$-modules, no?

Comment: I'm not familiar with whatever completed tensor product is being denoted by $\hat{\otimes}$ here.